# How does one build a quantile regression model?

Tags: quantile-regression

I'm confused about how to choose variables for a multivariable quantile regression? Do I just choose significant variables (regardless at what quantile they're significant) and add them to the model?

Comment: Often you want compare effects at different quantiles, and to that of OLS.

Comment: I understand the purpose of quantile regressions. I don't understand how to go about choosing the appropriate combination of variables. In OLS for example you usually run several univariable models and then build a multivariable model using the statistically significant variables from the univariable model. Is there a similar process for QR?